# Embed Pinterest widget in React

Tags: reactjs

I wrote the following component to embed a Pinterest widget in my React app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class PinterestWidget extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const script = document.createElement('script')

    script.async = true
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script['data-pin-build'] = 'doBuild'
    script.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }

  render() {
    const { url } = this.props

    return (
      <a data-pin-do="embedPin" data-pin-build="doBuild" href={url}>
        {url}
      </a>
    )
  }
}

export default PinterestWidget
```

It works fine when the component mount the first time.

But when I navigate to another route and go back to this page, it doesn't render the widget anymore.

I tried to place the script in `componentDidUpdate`, but no success.

PS: I searched for a component but the only one I found is [react-pinterest](https://github.com/pinterest/react-pinterest) which is not maintained for 2 years — and doesn't work in my app.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself in the exact same position today. After wrestling with forks of that same `react-pinterest` npm package I found a solution in this issue https://github.com/pinterest/widgets/issues/13.

It looks like you already got close by adding the `data-pin-build="doBuild"` data attribute but you aren't calling `doBuild()` when the user returns to the component after hitting a different route. Adding the data attribute instructs `pinit.js` to add `doBuild()` to the global scope but doesn't automatically call the function when you remount the component.

Try replacing your `componentWillMount` function with something like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if (!window.doBuild) {
    this.preloadWidgetScript();
  } else {
    window.doBuild();
  }
}

preloadWidgetScript = () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.dataset.pinBuild = 'doBuild';
  script.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

One other thing to note is the change from `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`, this is necessary to ensure the embed link is rendered before running `doBuild()`.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! It worked like a charm. Thanks for your help! ;)

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using the answer of @n33kos it works with `useEffect` and so far every time (without checking whether it has appended the script or not). Here the `<a>` link to pinterest exist in a markdown file that is injected as html

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.async = true
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.dataset.pinBuild = 'doBuild'
    script.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    if (window.doBuild) window.doBuild()
  }, []) // only run once
```